# Imperative client for autobahn WAMP server?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I'm using [autobahn](http://autobahn.ws) to run a websocket server to complement my Django app. Sometimes, I need to send messages from Django to the websocket server, which works fine using the [websocket-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client) module. I would love to use the WAMP protocol instead because the RPC/PubSub API looks great, but the python client code is implemented as a twisted protocol, and I can't figure out how to use that imperatively, i.e. like a function call and not from some foreign event loop. Is there anything I'm not seeing in the docs, or should my architecture be different?

Comment: Everything in Python is imperative.  I think you mean "blockingly" or maybe "synchronously".

Comment: Regarding architecture, there are (at least) 2 options: a) run Autobahn as a separate server and access that as a client from Django. b) run Django and Autobahn (server) within 1 process. There is an example for doing b) with Flask and Autobahn here https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/websocket/echo_wsgi/server.py

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: You're right, I want a synchronous, blocking call.

Comment: @oberstet: I do a) and the "access that as a client from Django" part is what I'm interested in. I can do it for a plain websocket server using a third-party module, but I don't know how to do a WAMP RPC call, e.g. from a Django view function.

Comment: @Simon a) is also what I'm looking for, but I'm wondering if making synchronous call to Twisted would not be a anti-pattern. That said, I don't know yet how to do it in another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/itamarst/crochet might help you out with this.

Comment: Interesting. And yeah, using this lib it seems you could do what you want: run Autobahn (client) within your app, but blocking (from your app POV).

Comment: Isn't it possible to just instantiate and use the WAMP client without running an event loop? Or would that require creating a full-blown "eventloop-less" implementation in addition to the Twisted & asyncio implementations?